# check output in MSTest unit test

Tags: c#, mstest, stdout, redirectstandardoutput

I want to capture output sent to standard out and standard error within an MSTest unit test so that I can verify it.  I've captured output before when explicitly running a `Process`, but is there a way to do with [I guess] the MSTest process itself?  For example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void OutputTest()
{
    MySnazzyMethod("input", 1, 'c');
    string stdOutFromMySnazzyMethod = /* ??? */;
    Assert.AreEqual("expected output", stdOutFromMySnazzyMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I liked [JaredPar's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298406/check-output-in-mstest-unit-test/2298583#2298583) but I didn't want to pass in `Console.Out` and `Console.Error` to every helper output method I had.  However, my output does go through a single class, so I just set a couple static fields in it:

```
internal static TextWriter _stdOut = Console.Out;
internal static TextWriter _stdErr = Console.Error;
```

I updated my output methods in the output handler class to make use of these fields.  I then updated that project's AssemblyInfo.cs to include:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProject")]
```

This way, I can override `_stdOut` and `_stdErr` in my test methods, call my method to be tested (which uses my output handling class), and confirm the output I expected.

```
OutputHandler._stdOut = new StringWriter();
MySnazzyMethod("input", 1, 'c');
OutputHandler._stdOut.Flush();
string expected = "expected output";
string stdout = OutputHandler._stdOut.ToString().Trim(new[] { '\r', '\n' });
Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdout));
Assert.AreEqual(expected, stdout);
```

Comment: Be careful with static fields in test classes. If you are going to use them, make sure to set OutputHandler._stdOut and/or OutputHandler._stdErr at the start of any test that uses them. MSTest unit test suites (not ordered tests) run in a nondeterministic fashion, so later tests in your run may not have these fields set properly to Console.Out and Console.Error before they try to use those TextWriters. (TestInitialize() and TestCleanup() don't guarantee any safety against this either.)

Comment: I think it's important to note that if you're changing the reference to Console.Out, you're not actually capturing standard output, but are faking/mocking it. This is good for a unit test, but not if what you're trying to test for is actual console output.

Comment: Also, 'stdout.ToString()' did not produce the desired text output in my own testing; it was the standard string representation of the class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a way to grab the output of an already running `Process`.  What you could do though is refactor your code slightly to not write to `Console.WriteLine` but instead take in a `TextWriter` instance and write to that.

In production you can then just pass `Console.Out` to the method.  In test code you could mock this type and provide much more accurate testing.  For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void OutputTest()
{
    var writer = new Mock<TextWriter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    writer.Setup(x => x.WriteLine("expected output")).Verifiable();
    MySnazzyMethod(writer.Object, "input", 1, 'c');
    writer.Verify();
}
```

Production Code

```
MySnazzyMethod(Console.Out, "input", 1, 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a couple [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) in the class initialize of your test classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Moles to redirect the call to `Console` writes to a lambda method inside your test code.

```
string result = ""; 
System.Moles.MConsole.WriteLineString = (s) =>
  { result = s; }; 
Assert.IsTrue(result == "The string I want", 
     "Failed to write to console correctly");
```

See page 16 in this document: [Moles Reference Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fpex%2Fmolesmanual.pdf&rct=j&q=using%20Moles%20to%20redirect%20DateTime.Now&ei=mIv2TLWoKo2osQPVvtmsCw&usg=AFQjCNEMIA-Jd4ba-HFixHRiGGi_c8v0-g&sig2=y4rsmFsmHAymy-ojC-nKNg&cad=rja).